# Loading values from file into a list and how to segregate them

Tags: python

I have a long list of values that I hard code in the program. As the list gets longer, it tends to get messy and I decided to put all these values in a file and the program will load the values from the file.

However, I encountered a problem.
If the values are coded in the program this way: fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Citrus"], python is able to segregate them into 3 strings.

Using the read from file method, python takes it as 1 string.

Both fruits and records are list type. Any idea why is that so? Also, any way to read from file and load as individual strings so that I can use forloop on the records list variable to get the values just like fruits list?

Thanks.

This is my code.

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Citrus"]
filepath = "C:\\Users\\vital\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\PythonInvestment\\loadfile.txt"
records=open(filepath).readlines()

print(type(fruits))
print(type(records))

for r in records:
    print("Display Value from file: "+r+'\n')

for t in fruits:
    print("Display value in tickers variable: "+t)
```

These are the results

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
Display Value from file: "Apple", "Banana", "Citrus"

Display value in tickers variable: Apple
Display value in tickers variable: Banana
Display value in tickers variable: Citrus
```

Comment: ```r.replace('"', '').split(', ')```, or if you can drop double quotes from your text file: ```r.split(',')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save all your words in one line in the file, after you load it, you should use split to get array. such as:

```
# a.txt
Apple,Banana,Citrus
```

Because just one line, you do not need use `readlines`, just use read.

```
with open('a.txt') as f:
   fruits = f.read().strip().split(',')

for t in fruits:
    print("Display value in tickers variable: "+t)
```